# How quickly display Minecraft Schematic to winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, gdi+, minecraft

There is my Code, But drawing is very slow:

```
        int BlockWidth = 16
        SourceBlueMap = new Bitmap(BlocksRect.Width, BlocksRect.Height);
        Graphics Gpi = Graphics.FromImage(SourceBlueMap);

        AlphaBlock block;

        string strPath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Blocks";

        BlockInfo blockinfo;


        for (int x = 0; x < iXDim; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < iYDim; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < iZDim; z++)
                {
                    block = Blocks.GetBlock(x, y, z);

                    rect.X = x * BlockWidth;
                    rect.Y = z * BlockWidth;

                    if (BlockInfoList.Exists(info =>
                        info.ID == block.ID && info.Data == block.Data))
                    {
                        blockinfo = BlockInfoList.Find(info =>
                        info.ID == block.ID && info.Data == block.Data);

                        if (File.Exists(strPath + "\\" + blockinfo.Name + ".png"))
                        {
                            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(strPath + "\\" + blockinfo.Name + ".png"))
                            {
                                Gpi.DrawImage(bmp, rect);
                            }
                        }
                    }  
                }
            }
        }

        Gpi.Dispose();
```

### Draw a 256 * 256 size map takes 6 seconds.

But other programs use draw than 1 second:
http://www.diamondpants.com/spritecraft/PayPalDonate.aspx

Comment: Move the File.Exists check outside the loop. That way FileSystem operation happens once. Make that Bitemap bmp variable also once in a wider scope than it is at the moment. You can also try Parallel.For and check if that makes things any better.

Comment: Also the right PixelFormat for the images is important. If the DrawImage method needs to convert PixelFormats it gets slow. Best performance can be achieved with PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I later checked under, "new Bitmap ()" is very time-consuming. Later use "Parallel.For", but multi-threaded can not be drawn at the same time, what should be done?

Comment: @ThomasVoß In fact, DrawImage quickly for me, the problem is "new Bitmap" there

Comment: @Zohn_Zhang: How many block-bitmaps are there? Couldn't you just cache them in a Dictionary<string, Bitmap>? If they don't exist you load them from file, otherwhise you reuse them.. I assume that the Bitmaps are reused quite often... But don't forget to properly dispose them after you have drawn them all...

Comment: @Zohn_Zhang: Additionally you can use the TextureBrush to fill the destination picture with the most used block-Bitmap before starting the loop. That can reduce draw calls massively if the same block-bitmap is used very often. But you must know which Bitmap is used most...

Comment: @ThomasVoß: I've done that. Thank you for your advice